# How to find a specific data file being used by a specific program

Tags: windows-7, database, data-transfer

I have a program ( I don't want to have its name here) which I enter data from time to time. So I believe it stores these data in a file somewhere on my PC. How can I find this data file and change it with another updated data file? I can’t locate this file. I would be grateful if someone help me.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer without knowing the name of the program? Without this any answer would just be guessing.

Comment: I am sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, luckily I found a software called Process explorer on the web, and this program shows which files a specific program uses on your computer.

Comment: The resource monitor (built in) can also be used to make discoveries of this type. In the disk tab, expand the disk activity section. in there you can also sort by the program. That will also continue to display for some time after a write or read.  A specific Process (your program) could also be selected as the "image" even in a different section, and what occurs with that program will be "filtered" to only it showing.  . . .  Whatever you do it would still be nice if you would have completed the original question to a fuller extent , so the info you provide has uses beyond your single need.